# No se enlazan los ficheros JS en el index con XDK

Tags: javascript, cordova, intel-xdk

Estoy empezando con XDK y creo que el index no está enlazando los archivos js, ya que a la hora de ejecutar no se activa el botón.

Éste es mi código:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="paginaLogin">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Login de usuario</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

        <form id="formularioLogin">
            <label>Télefono</label>
            <input type="number" id="telefonoLogin">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="passLogin">

            <input type="submit" value="login" id="btnlo" disabled="">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="codrdova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/devReadyConsola.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/Dialogos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>
    <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
</body>
```

Archivo devReadyConsola.js

```
*jslint browser:true, devel:true, white:true, vars:true */
/*global $:false, intel:false, document:false */
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){
console.log('\nEscribiendo a log!!\n');
$('#btnlo').button('enable');
}
```

Y el archivo Dialogos.js:

[image: Archivo Dialogos.js]

Comment: Debes poner todo el código en formato de texto y quitar la imagen, con imagen no podemos copiar tu problema para reproducirlo

Comment: Muchas gracias!! ya logre solucionarlo, por alguna extraña razón tuve que hacer otro proyecto y fue así como salió, aprovecho tus consejos para publicar ya que este fue mi primera pregunta. Saludos!!